# Crash With No Report

Tags: ios, swift, crash, crash-reports, avassetexportsession

I have a class within my program that combines a multitude of video files to produce 1 overall video. I have 1 main asset that I use primarily and apply the other assets on top. The only audio file used is from the main asset. Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Photos


class Merger: NSObject {

    var controller:EditVideoViewController!
    var button:AddAssetButton!
    var view:UIView!
    var difference:Double!
    var changed:Bool = false
    var AI:AIView!

    convenience init(controller:EditVideoViewController, button:AddAssetButton) {
        self.init()
        self.controller = controller
        self.button = button

        self.view = UIView(frame: controller.view.bounds)
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        self.controller.view.addSubview(self.view)
    }  

    func setupAI() {
        self.AI = AIView(view: self.view)
        self.AI.start()
    }

    func removeAI() {
        self.AI.stop()
        self.AI.removeEverything()
    }

    //The video is displaying in Portrait after merge.
    func merge(completion:@escaping () -> Void, assets:[Asset]) {

        self.setupAI()

        let assets = assets.sorted(by: { $0.layer.zPosition < $1.layer.zPosition })
        if let firstAsset = controller.firstAsset {

            let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

            let firstTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo,
                                                                     preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

            do {
                try firstTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, self.controller.realDuration),
                                           of: firstAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0],
                                           at: kCMTimeZero)
            } catch _ {
                print("Failed to load first track")
            }

            var myTracks:[AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []

            for asset in assets {

                let secondTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo,
                                                                          preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
                secondTrack.preferredTransform = asset.asset.preferredTransform
                do {
                    try secondTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.endTime-asset.beginTime),
                                               of: asset.asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0],
                                               at: CMTime(seconds: CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.beginTime), preferredTimescale: 600000))
                } catch _ {
                    print("Failed to load second track")
                }
                myTracks.append(secondTrack)
            }

            if let loadedAudioAsset = controller.audioAsset {
                let audioTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: 0)
                do {
                    try audioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, self.controller.realDuration),
                                               of: loadedAudioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0] ,
                                               at: kCMTimeZero)
                } catch _ {
                    print("Failed to load Audio track")
                }
            }

            let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
            mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, self.controller.realDuration)

            let firstInstruction = videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(firstTrack, firstAsset)
            var instructions:[AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction] = []
            var counter:Int = 0
            for tracks in myTracks {
                firstInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, at: assets[counter].beginTime)
                let secondInstruction = videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(tracks, assets[counter].asset, type:true)
                secondInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, at: assets[counter].endTime)
                firstInstruction.setOpacity(1.0, at: assets[counter].endTime)
                instructions.append(secondInstruction)
                counter += 1
            }

            mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [firstInstruction] + instructions
            let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
            mainComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
            mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
            mainComposition.renderSize = self.controller.firstAsset!.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0].naturalSize

            let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
            let savePath = (documentDirectory as NSString).appendingPathComponent("mergeVideo.mov")
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: savePath)
           _ = try? FileManager().removeItem(at: url)

            guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else { return }
            exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
            exporter.outputURL = url
            exporter.videoComposition = mainComposition


            exporter.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.exportDidFinish(exporter)
                    self.removeAI()
                    completion()
                })
            })
        }
    }
    func exportDidFinish(_ exporter:AVAssetExportSession) {
         if(exporter.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed) {
            print("cool")
        }
        else if(exporter.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed) {
            print(exporter.error as Any)
        }
    }

    func videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(_ track: AVCompositionTrack, _ asset: AVAsset, type:Bool = false) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {
        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
        let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]

        var transform = assetTrack.preferredTransform
        let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(transform)
        let width = self.controller.firstAsset!.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0].naturalSize.width/assetTrack.naturalSize.width
        var height = self.controller.firstAsset!.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0].naturalSize.height/assetTrack.naturalSize.height

        if assetInfo.isPortrait {
            //Vert Video taken from camera -- vert video from lib
            height = self.controller.firstAsset!.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0].naturalSize.height/assetTrack.naturalSize.width
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: height, y: height)
            let movement = ((1/height)*assetTrack.naturalSize.height)-assetTrack.naturalSize.height
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: movement)
            let totalBlackDistance = self.controller.firstAsset!.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0].naturalSize.width-transform.tx
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: -(totalBlackDistance/2)*(1/height))

        } else {
            //Main Video -- hor photo from camera -- hor video from camera -- hor photo frmo lib -- hor vid frmo lib -- vert photos lib - vert photos camera
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: width, y: height)
            let scale:CGFloat = ((self.controller.firstAsset!.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0].naturalSize.height/assetTrack.naturalSize.height)*(assetTrack.naturalSize.width))/self.controller.firstAsset!.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0].naturalSize.width
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: scale, y: 1)
            let movement = ((self.controller.firstAsset!.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0].naturalSize.width-((self.controller.firstAsset!.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0].naturalSize.height/assetTrack.naturalSize.height)*(assetTrack.naturalSize.width)))/2)*(1/(self.controller.firstAsset!.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0].naturalSize.height/assetTrack.naturalSize.height))
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: movement, y: 0)
        }
        instruction.setTransform(transform, at: kCMTimeZero)
        return instruction
    }

    func orientationFromTransform(_ transform: CGAffineTransform) -> (orientation: UIImageOrientation, isPortrait: Bool) {
        var assetOrientation = UIImageOrientation.up
        var isPortrait = false
        if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
            assetOrientation = .right
            isPortrait = true
        } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
            assetOrientation = .left
            isPortrait = true
        } else if transform.a == 1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == 1.0 {
            assetOrientation = .up
        } else if transform.a == -1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == -1.0 {
            assetOrientation = .down
        }

        return (assetOrientation, isPortrait)
    }
}
```

For my phone, iPhone 6s, this never crashes and I never have problems.

One of my testers, who has an iPhone 5s, randomly crashes while during the Exporting process. When his phone crashes, it doesn't seem to actually be crashing as much as terminating. The app completely closes and nothing happens. No crash report is sent to my Organizer window (this happens frequently) and there does not seem to actually be any problems. Another problem with testing this is his app does it on different ones. It doesn't crash everytime, even with the same assets chosen. If I could duplicate this problem regularly with some standardization, I wouldn't have so many problems. But, not really sure where to go from here.

**This tester is not located near me - I use Apple's Organizer Window to obtain crash reports**

**Potential Solutions:**

Memory: I was thinking this might be a memory issue, as I know if the memory is overloaded then it will teriminate the app. However, nothing is sent to "DidReceiveMemoryWarning", the app just terminates.

Any suggestions/solutions? All the help is appreciated.

Comment: Aren't there crash logs somewhere deep in the iOS settings app?

Comment: How would I obtain that from a tester that is not near me? I use crash logs from Xcode Organizer Crash Report

Answer (score 0):

The Xcode Organizer doesn't provide every single crash report there is for your app, only Apple knows how they select which they provide and which they don't provide. While beta testing via TestFlight it might sometimes take a few days for the report to arrive if the user approved providing crash report data to developers.

Even if the app would be killed by the OS for another reason, e.g. excessive memory consumption, a crash report would be written to the device and provided to Apple if all the requirements for providing it are positive, e.g. the user approved providing this data.

Without a report it is impossible to say what happened and why, so the assumption for a memory usage issue is a wild guess and the stated reason is not valid.

You need to get the crash report and symbolicate it. Your user can find the crash report on the device by navigating to "Settings > general > about > Diagnostics & usage data" and then copy the content and paste it e.g. into an email and send it to you.

Comment: I really appreciate this answer! I will need some time to do some research and see if this works out for me. If it does, I will give you full credit!

Comment: I was thinking - I get SOME of my tester's logs, just not this specific issue. Any known issue on that?

Comment: There are too many possibilities to say why this happens here and it is also unknown if Apple provides all reports with TestFlight or not.

Comment: I'm checking with the tester (they have not gotten back to me) to check your answer. It does help, as I didn't even know this information was located here